# Can iOS delete my App data when no free space

Tags: ios, memory-management

I want to know what iOS can do with my app data when the disk free space become very low. Can iOS delete some files to free disk space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont delete it, although [it can delete your caches in Library/Caches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). You need to conform to specs detailed in the link above, as your app might be rejected if you'll store something not where it should be (for example some caches in Documents).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing. To be a good citizen, you should do the following:

1. Any files that you can reproduce yourself should be marked as "don't backup". That saves lots of traffic to the cloud when there is no need to backup a file that you can just download again when needed.
2. Any files that you can afford to lose at any time should be in the temporary directory. These files will be deleted automatically (but you should not wait for them to be deleted automatically) at certain times and when the phone runs out of space.
3. Any files that you can reproduce should be in a "cache" directory to allow iOS to delete them.

The user can always delete all the files belonging to your application. Much better to mark anything that can be restored as "cached" so only what is essential is displayed in Settings as belonging to your app, and the user isn't tempted to throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** , iOS will not delete some files or data in your app. iOS will not delete user data automatically.

Comment: Any reference, doc... ?

Comment: caches and temp folders are not where  you should put your user data. Obviously temp and caches are not permanent storing places. User document folders would NEVER get deleted by iOS